# What's new in Razor 3?

Tags: asp.net, razor, razor-3

I can't find what's new in Razor 3. It seems like a silly question, but I can easily find what's new in MVC 5, in EF 6, etc. - but I tried to google it, I tried asp.net, I tried Scott's blog - nothing. So I'm curious, does anyone actually know what's new in Razor 3? Thanks!

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Razor/

Comment: What's wrong with this question that it was downvoted?

Comment: @scartag MVC 5 requires Razor 3.0 and Web Pages 3.0. See the notes for upgrading from MVC4 to MVC5 here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a list of all the bugs fixed in Razor 3.

https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/list/advanced?keyword=&status=Closed&type=All&priority=All&release=v5.0%2bPreview%7cv5.0%2bRC%7cv5.0%2bRTM&assignedTo=All&component=Web%2bPages%252fRazor&reasonClosed=Fixed&sortField=LastUpdatedDate&sortDirection=Descending&page=0

The three highlights are:

1. Support for editing with tabs in VS2013.
2. Support for URL rewrite
3. Removing of the security transparent attribute.

The official release notes are coming out shortly.

Comment: Release notes are now officially out:
http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/release-notes#TOC14

Answer (score 4):

There are no new features added in Razor 3 or Web Pages 3 - just some bug fixes. Given that, I have no idea why Microsoft haven't publicised any release notes specific to these two products. I have reached out to them on that. I shall update the answer when I get a response.

**UPDATE**

Yishai has kindly come back to me and provided details below as well.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to write them too before I posted this question - just out of the curiosity - so no response, so I just understand that once we want to switch to MVC5, we need to switch to Razor 3 as well. Or maybe in some long Winter nights I'll just check the source code... :)

Comment: I also considered getting Code Compare out, but in the meantime I am optimistic that I will get some kind of response. I know of one fix though - in relation to Web Pages validation controls not working in RenderPage scenarios in Web Pages 2. They do in version 3.